# Imitate ListView on left side of Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, treeview

I need a ListView that is like the listview on the right side of Windows Explorer. The ListView needs to have the expandable arrows. My idea, maybe use the ListView in a TreeView tempate?

Comment: Are you talking about Windows Explorer's Details view?

Comment: It's the pane with Favorite, Libraries, Homegroup, Computer, and Network as the main items. The very left pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your idea to re-template the treeview is probably a good one.  Optionally, you could consider a third part treeview like the one from Telerik that might provide more flexibility and make this task easier.

http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf.aspx